# xargs inconsistent behavior and -n1 parameter

Tags: linux, shell, xargs

I have a shell script

```
find . -name "*.java" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Lz 'regular_expression'
```

which outputs file names not matching the regexp in this way:

```
file1.java
file2.java
...
```

The way I understand, it works as follows: `find` find needed files and concatenate their names with `\0`. Then `xargs` split the output of `find` with `\0` and feeds them to `grep` one-by-one.

Then I wanted to add one more stage and get only `basename` of the files. I modified the script:

```
find . -name "*.java" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -LzZ 'regular_expression' | xargs -0 basename
```

but got an error. I started investigating and made an temporary output:

```
find . -name "*.java" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -LzZ 'regular_expression' | xargs -0  echo basename
```

and got this:

```
basename ./file1.java ./file2.java ./subdir/file1.java ./subdir/file2.java
```

So, the filenames were not split by `\0`. I can't get why they are split in case of `xargs` used with `grep` and not split in `xargs` with `basename`.

I got a workaround by using `-n1` in the latter `xargs`. But still I don't understand why I needed it (given I didn't use in in the `xargs` with `grep`) and what this parameter does.

Hope you can explain to me what `-n1` does and why I needed it in the latter usage and didn't need it in the former with `grep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filenames *were* split by `\0`.  The difference is in the commands you're using.  `xargs` normally takes its standard input, breaks it into a list (here, by splitting on NUL), and then passes that list as extra arguments to your command.  So when you do this:

```
find . -name "*.java" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Lz 'regular_expression'
```

What actually runs is this:

```
grep -Lz 'regular_expression' file1.java file2.java file3.java...
```

Here, the `-z` doesn't matter because it only affects how `grep` reads stdin, and you're not sending anything to its stdin.

So, when you add another `xargs` that runs `basename`, you get this:

```
basename file1.java file2.java file3.java...
```

But while `grep` will take any number of filename arguments, *`basename` only takes one* and ignores the others.

That's where `-n 1` comes in: it tells `xargs` to break its list of arguments into chunks (of 1), and run the command multiple times.  So what runs now is:

```
basename file1.java
basename file2.java
basename file3.java
...
```

And all the output is concatenated together onto stdout.

Comment: Thank you! I got it. I want to ask one more ill-related question. Why does it suggested to use `-print0` with `find` and then parse it with `xargs`. Why can't we use some other parameter with `find` to join filenames with space (without all this stuff with joining with zero, then splitting by zero with `xargs` and then joining with space)?

Comment: `find` will delimit with newlines by default, and `xargs` will split on any whitespace by default.  alas, an oft-forgotten quirk of the unix world is that filenames can contain _any character_ except NUL and slash, _including newlines_.  (for this reason i try to use crazy zsh shell globs instead of `find` whenever i can, so i just don't have to think about it.)

Comment: Thank you again! You helped me a lot! I have been thinking about this issue with `xargs` for a day or two. You also mentioned `-z` being useless as it affects only `stdin` and not arguments, which is fact very important (I'm just a novice with shell scripts, so I didn't pay much attention to these things before). Now I think I understand shell a bit better.

Answer (score 10):

`-n1` tells `xargs` to *run the given command **once per argument**.*

So if you have something like

```
echo file1 file2 file2 | xargs basename
```

That's equivalent to passing all arguments at once to a single call to the `basename` command, like this:

```
basename file1 file2 file2
```

But if you do

```
echo file1 file2 file2 | xargs -n1 basename
```

That will cause xargs to pass only *one* argument (due to `-n1`) to the `basename` call, per instance of the call, like this:

```
basename file1 
basename file2 
basename file2
```

As for the `-0` flag in `xargs`, that's an alias to the `--null` option which tells `xargs` to identify separate arguments by looking for a binary zero (`\0`) null character between them instead of the default whitespace between them. You need it after `find` because `find` is set to use binary zero separators (`\0`) via the `-print0` option, and `grep` then needs the `-z` argument to do the same thing.

Comment: Should the second example be: `echo file1 file2 file2 | xargs -n1 basename`? (it's missing the `-n1` option)